# php: Unable to take value from the user by using submit button

Tags: php, html, sql

This is my db : [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n81lL.png) [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aftub.png)

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","organisation");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM org_insert");

echo "<!doctype html>
<html lang=\"en\">
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css\">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>below_whom</th>
<th>name</th>
</tr>";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
#echo '<pre>'; print_r($row); echo '</pre>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['below_whom'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="usr">below_whom:</label>
  <input type="text" name ="below_whom" id="below_whom" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="usr">name:</label>
  <input type="text" name ="name" id="name" class="form-control">
</div>
<form method="post">
    <input  type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","organisation");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if($below_whom !=''||$name !=''){
        $below_whom=$_POST['below_whom'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $query=mysqli_query("INSERT INTO org_insert VALUES ('$below_whom','$name');");
        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        echo "<p>query inserted.</p>";
    }else{
            echo "<p>Insertion Failed.</p>";
            }
}
mysqli_close($con);

echo"</body>
    </html>";
?>
```

The text under p tag isn't getting executed, ie, the program is not going inside the if statement itself. I have rechecked the syntax, what is the problem? Is the syntax incorrect? I am pretty sure the connection with sql is correct. I have also refereed to some articles, still I am stuck here.

Comment: put form start tag on top of form not top of submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use post variables before if loop as shown below

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$below_whom=$_POST['below_whom'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
    if($below_whom !=''||$name !=''){

        $query=mysqli_query("INSERT INTO org_insert VALUES ('$below_whom','$name');");
        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        echo "<p>query inserted.</p>";
    }else{
            echo "<p>Insertion Failed.</p>";
            }
}
```

and in HTML Code add type as submit and start form tag before div as 
`<form method="post" action="">` and closes after input tag

```
<input  type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues that I am able to see is that Your query should be:

```
$query=mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `org_insert`(`below_whom`,`name`) VALUES ('$below_whom','$name')");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change the mysqli_fetch_array to mysqli_fetch_assoc or add a parameter too

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: That doesn't make any diferrence because the mysqli_fetch_array gives the combined result of simple and associative array.